# How long was Daisy Ridley/Rey's hair?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, costume

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, Rey is wearing a distinctive hairstyle.  If I want to replicate it for a cosplay, I need to have an idea how long to grow out my hair.  However, she keeps her hair in that hairstyle throughout the film, so I don't have a solid idea of how long her hair was to pull off that style.

How long should your hair be to duplicate Rey's hairstyle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily someone has already posted up a Youtube video tutorial, showing you how to do it. In the video she states that your hair must be *at least* shoulder length, however it's clear her hair is a few inches longer than this, as the ends are below the view of the camera:

So basically you'll need it to be a few inches below the shoulder or longer.

Comment: We actually never see how long her hair is, since the camera cuts off at the shoulders. We can only tell that her hair is at least longer than shoulder length.

Comment: Edited my answer.